# Set JSpinner model programmatically

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I need to set `JSpinner` model according to some parameters, like if something is X then change the spinner model.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
SpinnerNumberModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(new Float(0.1), new Float(0.0), new Float(0.9), new Float(0.1));                              
JSpinner.NumberEditor ed = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(sMySpiner);
sMySpiner= new JSpinner(model);
sMySpiner.setEditor(ed);
```

But the problem is that new model is not applied after setting. Is there missing something?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can also reproduce your problem. This will also help us to provide a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
sMySpiner= new JSpinner(model);
```

To:

```
sMySpiner.setModel(model);
```

It's likely that changing the reference to the existing spinner is not updating the spinner seen on screen. If that change fails to solve the problem, post an MCVE as suggested by Sergiy.